# Pointer declared outside of try/catch but initialized inside causes undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a some code that looks like the following:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA(string p1, string p2);
    void DoSomething();
};

int main()
{
    ClassA *p = NULL;

    try
    {
        // ...
        // some external input that can throw
        // ...
        ClassA a{"some", "params"};
        p = &a;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        // print error
    }

    if (p != NULL) {
        p->DoSomething(); // <- causes segfault
    }
}
```

Apologies if this is bad/stupid code (I'm new to C++), but why does calling `a->DoSomething()` cause segfaults to occur? Clearly, `p` is declared out of the try/catch block's scope, and the `p != NULL` always returns true, showing that `p` is not null and thus was properly initialized inside of the try/catch block.

Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: 'a' goes out of scope once it leaves the {} block.  So now `p` points to something that no longer exists

Comment: p still points to the address of a even after going of scope but the value in pointer is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer is initialized to point to an instance of an object in automatic inner scope.

When execution thread leaves the scope, the object is destroyed, and the pointer is now pointing to a destroyed object.

And a thrown exception, of course, leaves the scope where the object is declared.

In other words, the object that the pointer is pointing to only exists inside the `try` block, and as soon as execution leaves the `try` block, naturally, or via a thrown exception, the object gets destroyed.

The fact that the exception gets the caught by the `catch` block, is irrelevant.

This is yet another reason to use smart pointers. If the object gets allocated in dynamic scope, and the pointer in question is a `unique_ptr` or a `shared_ptr`, the object remains perfectly accessible, via the smart pointer, in the `catch` block, with no additional work required.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer `p` points to local object `a` which lifetime is limited to `try` block. Outside of that block you are having dangling pointer. Hence Undefined Behavior that leads to segfault.